# How to get last-modified from http header with dartio HttpClient

Tags: flutter, dart, http-headers, httpclient

Hi there I want get Last_modified from http header with dart.io HttpClient()

code sample is:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest req = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("sayagh.asnafhormozgan.ir/wp-content/tables/essentials.csv"));
  var a = req.headers.value("lastModifiedHeader");
```

but a returns  null;

how I can get Last modified?

but when I get it with curl:

```
curl -v "sayagh.asnafhormozgan.ir/wp-content/tables/drawer.csv"
*   Trying 51.89.173.235:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sayagh.asnafhormozgan.ir (51.89.173.235) port 80 (#0)
> GET /wp-content/tables/drawer.csv HTTP/1.1
> Host: sayagh.asnafhormozgan.ir
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Thu, 19 Sep 2019 10:05:37 GMT
< Content-Type: text/csv
< Content-Length: 599
< Connection: keep-alive
< Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Sep 2019 09:38:30 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Cache-Control: max-age=0
< Expires: Thu, 19 Sep 2019 10:05:37 GMT
<
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wait for the second future to get the response, i.e.:

> A getUrl request is a two-step process, triggered by two Futures. When
>   the first future completes with a HttpClientRequest, the underlying
>   network connection has been established, but no data has been sent. In
>   the callback function for the first future, the HTTP headers and body
>   can be set on the request. Either the first write to the request
>   object or a call to close sends the request to the server.

See https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html

Also it should be `'last-modified'` and not `'lastModifiedHeader'` (or even better use the static const variable `HttpHeaders.lastModifiedHeader`), e.g.:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient();
HttpClientRequest req = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(
    'http://sayagh.asnafhormozgan.ir/wp-content/tables/essentials.csv'));
HttpClientResponse response = await req.close();
print(response.headers.value(HttpHeaders.lastModifiedHeader));
```

Comment: it means first req should download file? isnt any way i can check before downloading file?

Comment: I guess you could have a look at the HEAD action, as opposed to GET, if the server supports it. The server will then only respond with headers without a body, see https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-io/HttpClient/headUrl.html